# Does Foursquare have a maximum number or frequency of API requests?

Tags: api, foursquare

I want to build an application which will use a lot of data, trying to "understand" in which roads there is traffic based on the users' check-ins, so it is important for me to know how many data I can request from foursquare. Reading the Foursquare API Platform Policy I found that

> Foursquare expressly reserves the right to limit the number and/or frequency of API requests in its sole discretion

Does anybody know if there is a maximum number or frequency of API requests or this limition only exist for malicious attacks?

Comment: Just as an aside, is this for a smart phone? If so, your users might not have unlimited data plans, so be careful.

Comment: no, the application will run in cloud. i just need foursquare api to get information about the places where a lot of people have been gathered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 requests per hour for user related requests. 5000 request per hours for userless requests. If you need more, they allow you to email them and apply for it. You can read in depth here.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits

Comment: Can you mark it as the best answer? Im trying to get my rep points up. :)

Comment: i 've clicked the answer to be the accepted one, but can't vote it up... still a newbie!